# Redirect to profile after login (PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

I'm attempting to redirect users to their profile, with their username in the header. However, the redirect does not display the username. The login page asks for email and password (username omitted). Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

In class.php:

```
public function register($uname,$email,$upass,$code)
{
try
{       
$password = md5($upass);
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userEmail,userPass,tokenCode) 
                                            VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, 
:user_pass, :active_code)");
$stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$uname);
$stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
$stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
$stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
$stmt->execute(); 
return $stmt;
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
echo $ex->getMessage();
}
}

public function login($email,$upass,$uname)
{
try
{
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE 
userEmail=:email_id AND userName=:user_name");
$stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email,":user_name"=>$uname));
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
{
if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
{
 if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
 {
  $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
  $_SESSION['userName'] = $userRow['userName'];
  return true;
```

The redirect code:

```
public function redirectchannel()
{
header("Location: index.php?id=$userName");
}
```

login page:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
$email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
$upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);

if($user_login->login($email,$upass))
{
$user_login->redirectchannel();
}
}

<input type="email" class="reginput" placeholder="Email address" name="txtemail" required />
<input type="password" class="reginput" placeholder="Password" name="txtupass" required />
<button class="formbutton" type="submit" name="btn-login">Login</button>
```

And landing page:

```
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Where do you call redirectchannel ?

Comment: And where's the code that actually displays anything?  There's a lot missing here.

Comment: The redirectchannel is called on login page. Updated the question.

Comment: hashing your password with `md5` is not secure use `password_hash` and `password_verify`

Comment: Thank you, I will change that.

Comment: And code for `index.php` is? And what is `$userName` in redirect function?

Comment: `$user_login->login($email,$upass)` vs `public function login($email,$upass,$uname)` is surely throwing a warning, no? And the lack of `$uname` to bind is, at best, causing your query to return no results, if not causing it to throw an exception. What debugging have you done here? As I said before, there's a lot missing here. Not a very well presented question.

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't know **why** you put username in a query string, as you already have it in a session, but still:

```
public function redirectchannel()
{
    // what is `$userName` here? It is NULL    
    header("Location: index.php?id=$userName");
}
```

So, if you still want to pass username as query parameter, I suppose you can do:

```
public function redirectchannel()
{
    header("Location: index.php?id=" . $_SESSION['userName']);
    exit; //always exit immediately after location headers.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you don't need to pass the user name value through the URL. You're already creating a session variable with the user name:

```
$_SESSION['userName']
```

You can use this same variable in any page using the same session. Simply create a variable like:

```
$username = $_SESSION['userName'];
```

Now you can call this variable at any time on the page like so:

```
User Name: <?php echo $username; ?>
```